# Firebase onDisconnect taking too much time to update realtime database when user suddenly lost network

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on making a chat app using firebase, where I need to know instantly that user is online or offline. But when user lost his network suddenly then onDisconnect method comes in the picture. But it is taking too much time to update realtime database.

Here is my Code. Please share better solution to this problem.

```
        DatabaseReference infoConnected = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/connected");
        final DatabaseReference UpdateRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/Status/"+mAuth.getUid());
        infoConnected.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                boolean isCon = dataSnapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
                if(isCon)
                {
                   DatabaseReference reference = UpdateRef.child("Status");
                   reference.setValue("Online");

                   reference.onDisconnect().setValue("Offline");

                }
            }
```

Thanks in advance.